# How to parameterize GivenStories as well as the current story I am testing?

Tags: bdd, reusability, parameterized, jbehave

I want to reuse some of the steps that are common. for example

```
Scenario: Navigate to Page 2 and perform first set of validations
Given A user<username> is logged in
When user clicks on <menuItem>
and page <page_name> is displayed
and user clicks on Submit button
Then Page <second_page> is displayed
And validate <condition_1>

Scenario: Navigate to Page 2 and perform second set of validations
Given A user<username> is logged in
When user clicks on <menuItem>
and page <page_name> is displayed
and user clicks on Submit button
Then Page <second_page> is displayed
And validate <condition_2>

Examples:
|username|page_name|menuItem|condition_1|condition_2|
|username1|Page1|Menu1|Condition1|Condition2|
```

Now, Since the given conditions are same, I would like to normalize the story to something like this.

In precondition1.story

```
Given A user<username> is logged in
When user clicks on <menuItem>
and page <page_name> is displayed
and user clicks on Submit button
Then Page <second_page> is displayed
```

In currentTestStory.story

```
GivenStories: precondition1.story

Scenario: Navigate to Page 2 and perform first set of validations
Given Page <second_page> is displayed
And validate <condition_1>

Scenario: Navigate to Page 2 and perform second set of validations
Given Page <second_page> is displayed
And validate <condition_2>

Examples:
|username|page_name|menuItem|condition_1|condition_2|
|username1|Page1|Menu1|Condition1|Condition2|
```

But the challenge I am facing is, I cannot parameterize the GiveStory from the current story. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to not use GivenStories at all in this story. Use the step

```
Given Page <second_page> is displayed
```

and then do whatever it takes in the step in order to display that second page.

Comment: Andreas..That is what we are doing as on date. Looks like JBehave is not entirely reusable. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It depends. IMHO stories should still be tests. And no scripting or programming. First concern should be to write clean, precise and understandable tests. If you can then reuse steps, that's fine. If not: deal with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You CAN parameterize the Given story from the current story.

See section "GivenStories parametrized by Examples" on page http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html

The drawback is that you have to modify the code and add @Named annotation to your java steps. So according to the example in the page, the following method can take care of the parameters in the example:

```
@When("Something happens")
public void happening(@Named("One") String one, @Named("Two") String two) {
    //Do good
}
```

Comment: Hi Joachim
Thanks for the response. I have gone through this page earlier. 
"Conventionally, if the examples table is used to parametrized the GivenStories (i.e. if anchors are present in the story paths), it is assumed we are not using it to parameterize the scenario at the same time. This behaviour may be made configurable in the future, depending on the need."

My question was exactly about the quoted statement on the page. My scenario requires parameterized steps in both GivenStories and current story.